# Problem with Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 on XP

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machines, windows-virtual-pc

I have installed and run Virtual PC 2007 and have a virtual instance running,  but the Virtual PC program 'stopped working' on my host machine.

I have installed and used Micrsoft Virtual PC 2007 on a number of machines before and not had this issue.

I can still double click on the .vmc file and it will start up the virtual instance but if I want to change/look at the settings I cant do that.

ie on the host machine I do Start > Microsoft Virtual PC an icon appears in the task bar but never maximises, when I click on the icon it disappears.

Has anyone else got this issue? Does anyone know how to fix it?

I have un-installed/re-installed Virtual PC and this did not fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just reinstalled Virtual PC with service pack 1 and that works.

I was previously trying the version without the service pack, strange how it worked a few times before stopping.